# distribution of difference of max and min of uniformly random values

Tags: probability

> $X$ and $Y$ are two iid $\mathrm U(0,1)$ random variables. If
>   $$Z=\max(2X,Y)-\min(2X,Y)$$
>   (1) What is the pdf and cdf of $Z$?
>   (2) What is the probability that $Z<\frac13$?

I know that cdf of $max(X,Y)$ is $x^2$. I know that cdf of $max(2X,Y)$ is $\frac{x^2}{2}$. I know that pdf of $min(2X,Y)$ is $1-\frac{(1-x)^2}{2}$. But I dont know why I can find distribution of difference and probability.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where did you get stuck? Add that to your question.

Comment: I know that pdf of $max(X,Y)$ is $x^2$. I know that pdf of $max(2X,Y)$ is $\frac{x^2}{2}$. I know that pdf of $min(2X,Y)$ is $1-\frac{(1-x)^2}{2}$. But I dont know why I can find distribution of difference and probability.

Comment: If you add that to your question (so not in a comment) then you increase the chances that someone will help you.

Comment: This is a case when drawing a picture helps immensely (to the point of providing a full answer).

Comment: ((Anecdotally, the PDF you suggest for $\max(2X,Y)$ is incorrect, and it is not the CDF either.))

Comment: Why PDF  for max(2X,Y) = $x^2/2$ is incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $Z=|2X-Y|$ and takes values in $[0,2)$.

So if $F_Z$ denotes the CDF of $Z$ then evidently $F_Z(z)=1$ if $z\geq2$ and $F_Z(z)=0$ if $z<0$.

For a fixed $z\in[0,2)$ let $h_z(x,y)$ take value $1$ if $|2x-y|\leq z$ and let it take value $0$ otherwise.

Then:$$F_Z(z)=\Pr(h_z(X,Y)=1)=\mathbb Eh_z(X,Y)=\int^1_0\int^1_0h_z(x,y)dxdy$$

This comes to the same as finding the area of: $$\{\langle x,y\rangle\in(0,1)^2\mid|2x-y|\leq z\}=\{\langle x,y\rangle\in(0,1)^2\mid-z\leq2x-y\leq z\}$$

If you have found the CDF then it is not difficult to find $\Pr(Z<\frac13)$, and you can find the PDF by taking the derivative of the CDF.